# Best protocol for UDP streaming

Tags: udp, streaming, rtmp, rtp

Currently, I'm using open source code from OBS multiplatform for my video streaming application. But OBS uses RTMP for streaming, which only works on TCP. I want to use UDP since this is a live streaming scenario where I don't desire latency.

What is the best way to move to UDP? I read that protocols like RTP support UDP. Is this the best option to use? How about writing a simple UDP socket code to send and receive video data? Please guide.

The reason for trying to move to UDP is to ensure minimum latency between client and server. I'm looking for a quickest way to move to a udp based streaming than the current RTMP which uses TCP. I'm not very experienced in networking related coding. Will a simple socket program suffice to stream a video data continuously or should I implement a protocol like RTP? Or any other alternative? Ultimately, streaming should be smooth with minimum latency.

Comment: First you need to define 'best' for your purposes.

Comment: I've edited my question. Hope that makes it more clear?

Comment: Transporting media over UDP is a complex thing.  RTP was designed for UDP.  You also have to understand that a lost packet will result in the video being temporarily corrupted.  UDP gains latency reduction but looses protection against lost packets.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am planning to use RTSP for first sending the SDP and then stream media over RTP (on top of UDP). Yes, I understand that there will be packet loss causing video artifacts. Are there any ways to overcome or lesser the implications? With TCP, network bandwidth is hitting its limit quite often so I am forced to move to UDP.